# C# Exception Handling - will last catch block fetch re-thrown Exception?

Tags: c#, exception

I'm wondering if this code will work in the way that after 10 retries `CleanUp()` will be called? Or will the `throw new Exception()` not get caught by the last catch block?

```
public void Process()
{
    try
    {}
    catch (MyException e)
    {           
        int retries = GetRetries();
        if(retries > 10)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Retried event already {retries} times. Giving up.", retries);
            throw new Exception("Giving up!");
        }

        Process();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        CleanUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to know what happens when you run the code then *run the code* and see what happens.  Why are you asking us what your code does when you run it?

Comment: Don't use exceptions for normal control flow

Comment: Because the code is a lot more complex than this and it will take some effort to create the actual condition. Hence I tried to simplify this as much as I could. And the general question is hopefully clear.

Comment: @silent I think you don't need your complex code to test this - [try it out](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U5nK3a)

Comment: If you want to retry `Process` then you need to have a loop that contains a try around the `Process` with a catch that will throw once you hit the retry threshold.  And then you can have a try catch around all of that for the `CleanuUp` (or a finally if that makes more sense).  An empty `try` is pointless unless you're just not showing the code in your `try` for brevity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't work like that. For any given `try`/`catch` block, only an exception originating in the `try` can be caught by the corresponding `catch` blocks. Exceptions thrown within `catch` blocks are not catchable by other `catch` blocks at the same level.

`finally` blocks allow you to run code when control leaves a `try`/`catch` for *any* reason. So if the end of your `try` already has a `CleanUp` then you would just change your final `catch(Exception e)` to `finally` and remove the `CleanUp` at the end of the `try` part.

If, however, you only want to run `CleanUp` when control leaves the `try`/`catch` *via an exception*, you're not so lucky. There is a `fault` clause in IL, which is `finally`, but only for exceptions, but that's not exposed in C#.

So if you need that, it's usually best to introduce an extra `bool` that indicates you reached the end of the `try` block without exception, and use that to make your `CleanUp` call conditional in the `finally`.

---

Or you may simulate `try`/`catch`/`fault` by nesting `try`/`catch` blocks:

```
try
{
    try
    {}
    catch (MyException e)
    {           
        int retries = GetRetries();
        if(retries > 10)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Retried event already {retries} times. Giving up.", retries);
            throw new Exception("Giving up!");
        }

        Process();

    }
}
catch
{
  //Act as fault
  CleanUp();
  throw;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I was trying to clarify.

Comment: As written this code will do exactly nothing because that inner `try` is empty and therefor does not throw so the inner `catch` will never run and thus no exceptions will occur in the outer `try` and the outer `catch` will also not run.  I suspect the OP really wants the `try` around the `Process` if this is meant to be retry code.

Comment: @juharr - yes, I took it as "contents of the `try` omitted for brevity". Empty `try` blocks are pointless.